# Why can't I reassign an integer value in a while loop?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, while-loop, variable-assignment, cin

I'm creating (what should be) a very simple code to calculate some movie prices. I need the following input variables : movie_title, adult_tickets_sold, child_tickets_sold. I'm trying to add exceptions in case someone enters something other than an integer for the tickets sold variables. Something like this in python:

```py
favorite_number = None
while True:
    tmp = input("Enter your favorite number: ")
    try:
        favorite_number = int(tmp)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter an integer value please...")
```

And this is the loop I have now in C++ (only working on one input at the moment):

```cpp
while (con==true){
        cout << "How many adult tickets sold? " << endl;
        cin >> bigBoy;

        if (cin.fail()){
            cout << "\nYou entered text instead of a number!\nLet's try that again!\n\n"<< endl;
            cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
            cin >> bigBoy;
            continue;
        }
        cout << "How many children tickets sold? " << endl;
        cin >> lilSquirt;

        con=false;
    }
```

Whenever the if-statement is triggered, it completely ignores the 'cin's and infinitely prints this:

```
You entered text instead of a number!
Let's try that again!


Please enter an integer: How many adult tickets sold?
```

No idea why this is happening.

Comment: add `cin.clear();` before `cin >> bigBoy;`

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the usual idiom for checking input is to use the conversion from a steam to a `bool`. Like this: `while (!(std::cin >> bigBoy)) { /* stuff to clean stream and re-prompt */ }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (cin.fail()){
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(22,'\n');
        cout << "\nYou entered text instead of a number!\nLet's try that again!\n\n"<< endl;
        cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
        cin >> bigBoy;
      //  continue;
    }
```

you have to clear the cin. Also comment out continue statement if you want adult ticket and child ticket both .